# For loop that takes in inputs for different items sold, calculates a total based on various prices, and prints the quantity and total at the end

Tags: python

So for my python class, we’ve been instructed to create a for loop that will ask the user to input a quantity of an item sold, where the string literal is supposed to be “Quantity of item 1: ” and so on, for a total of 5 different items. Then it calculates the price of the item * the quantity and comes up with a total for each SEPERATE  item. The gimmick is that we can’t use lists and it HAS to be a for loop. The professor also gave us a hint that we’ll be using if/else/elif statements.

The code I’ve come up with so far is

```
for x in range(1,6):
    quantity = int(input("quantity of item " +str(x)+ " : "))
    if x == 1:
        total = quantity * 2.50
    elif x == 2:
        total = quantity * 1.98
    elif x == 3:
        total = quantity * 5.75
    elif x == 4:
        total = quantity * 3.45
    elif x == 5:
        total = quantity * 4
print(quantity)
```

The problem with this code is that it only prints the totals of the last elif statement. I’m trying to refrain from making too many variables as that would defeat the purpose of the loop.

Comment: why not just move the print statement inside the for loop?

Comment: all youre doing is printing the last int assigned to quantity

Comment: I moved it to the outside of the for loop because the program has to print out everything at the very end.

Comment: @JackDegennaro You should have specified the desired end result. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Probably what you're missing is that `=` operator override whatever was in that variable before, so everytime you do `total = something`, `total` gets overridden to `something`.
Probably what you want to use is `+=`, which will add to `total` what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `+=` rather than just `=` because `=` overwrites what was previously in the variable when you want to keep the total sum.

You also made a mistake with the `print` statement. Presumably you want the `total`, but the variable you have in the `print` is `quantity`.

See the working code below.

```
total = 0
for x in range(1,6):
    quantity = int(input("quantity of item " +str(x)+ " : "))
    if x == 1:
        total += quantity * 2.50
    elif x == 2:
        total += quantity * 1.98
    elif x == 3:
        total += quantity * 5.75
    elif x == 4:
        total += quantity * 3.45
    elif x == 5:
        total += quantity * 4
print(total)
```

Comment: OP said total for each separate item

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(1,6):

    quantity = int(input("quantity of item " + str(x)+ " : "))
    if x == 1:
        total = quantity * 2.50
        Print("quantity: " + str(x) + " Total: " + str(total))
    elif x == 2:
        total = quantity * 1.98
        Print("quantity: " + str(x) + " Total: " + str(total))
    elif x == 3:
        total = quantity * 5.75
        Print("quantity: " + str(x) + " Total: " + str(total))
    elif x == 4:
        total = quantity * 3.45
        Print("quantity: " + str(x) + " Total: " + str(total))
    elif x == 5:
        total = quantity * 4
        Print("quantity: " + str(x) + " Total: " + str(total))
```

The reason why your code only prints the last item because you didn't save the previous values. When you assigned quantity equal to a variable that changes each loop, it replaces the previous value.

for example:

```
for i in range(3):
    num = i
print(num)
```

Because num will be replaced by the next value in this loop. We know the last value in range(3) is 2.

Since print statement is outside of for loop, it does not get affected by the loop and only print the last value which again is 2.
**If you want all of them in one string**, you can concatenate them into a string by first declaring a variable assign to an empty string where you can store the values. See below:

```
for x in range(1,6):

    FinalOutput = ""

    quantity = int(input("quantity of item " + str(x)+ " : "))
    if x == 1:
        total = quantity * 2.50
        FinalOutput += "Quantity: " + str(x) + " Total: " + str(total) + " , "

    elif x == 2:
        total = quantity * 1.98
        FinalOutput += "Quantity: " + str(x) + " Total: " + str(total) + " , "
    elif x == 3:
        total = quantity * 5.75
        FinalOutput += "Quantity: " + str(x) + " Total: " + str(total) + " , "

    elif x == 4:
        total = quantity * 3.45
        FinalOutput += "Quantity: " + str(x) + " Total: " + str(total) + " , "
    elif x == 5:
        total = quantity * 4
        FinalOutput += "Quantity: " + str(x) + " Total: " + str(total) + " , "

print(FinalOutPut)
```